# Which properties are , and are not, inherited by the sample moments from population moments?

Tags: statistics

Usually we learn that $\text{Cov}(aX+bY,cZ+lW)=\text{acCov}(X,Z)+\text{alCov}(X,W)+\text{bcCov}(Y,Z)+\text{blCov}(Y,W)$
Defining the sample covariance as $s_{X,W}=1/n\sum\left(x_i-\bar x\right)\left(w_i-\bar w\right)$, we also have $$s_{aX+bY,cZ+lW}=ac\ s_{X,Z}+al \ s_{X,W}+bc\ s_{Y,Z}+bl\ s_{Y,W}$$

What other analogous properties are valid?

More importantly, are there analogous properties which are not valid?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Let $X$ and $Y$ be continuous r.v., thus 
$$
cov(X,Y) = E(X-EX)(Y-EY) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} \int_{\mathbb{R}} (X-EX)(Y-EY)dxdy, 
$$
now, its sample analogue ("estimator") is the same thing just without the limit, i.e., 
$$
\widehat{cov(X,Y)} = \frac{1}{n}\sum(x_i - \bar{x})(x_i - \bar{y}).
$$
Where the later is strongly consistent estimator of the covariance, namely, it converges a.s. to the aforementioned integral when $n\to \infty$. In other words, the population-wise covariance can be seen as a limiting sample covariance, thus they are basically (almost) the same mathematical objects (summation and integration), as such they bear the same properties (which is the linearity of summation/integration).